# where can I find good reference document on python exception

Tags: python, exception, reference

It doesn't seem easy to find good reference document that details all python exceptions.

For example, whenever I got IOError exception, it has a different message format but I could not find any good reference:

```
IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
```

or

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

Built-in Exceptions are [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html), here's [IOException](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError). Check [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno) documentation for symbol definition, `errno.errorcode` is a dict containing a mapping between error code/symbols.

```
import errno
errno.errorcode[numeric_code]
```

Comment: You do have to follow a couple of links to get to the real meat of the issue in http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno and you would need to read the source of the errno module to learn which one is 110.

Answer (score 1):

I [guess](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) that you are looking for [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html):

```
try:
    open('file_dont_exist')
except IOError as ex:
    if ex.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        print "no such file or directory"
```